# How to list all methods of a class (not Extended and Included methods)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-2.2

Using Ruby 2.2.1, How to list all methods (preferrably Array of String names) of a class that is only defined in that class / file where `include` and `extend` methods are filtered out. I want to distinguish class and instance methods as well.

Currently, I can get all the uninherited methods using `MyClass.methods(false)` but this still includes methods that are part of an `include` Module.

Explicitly, say, I have:

```
class MyClass < BaseClass
  extend AnotherBaseClass
  include MyModule

  def foo
  end
  
  def bar
  end
end
```

I want to get:

```
somecodethatreturnssomething
#=> ['foo', 'bar']
# Not including BaseClass, AnotherBaseClass, and ModuleClass methods
```

**UPDATE:**

[@Wand Maker's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34357723/4575793) is correct when I run it in a separate irb console. However, I still have a problem specifically that  I am including `ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper` in `MyClass`. I always get extra methods: `default_url_options?`, `default_url_options=`, and `default_url_options`. I thought that include behaves the same regardless of Rails  or not, so I didn't tag this question with Rails.

I even added `byebug` at the end of the file of `MyClass`, so that I could inspect the class and run `MyClass.singleton_methods(false)` or run `MyClass.instance_methods(false)`. But they still include these three unwanted methods.

I can remove these three extra methods from the array manually, so I could get the dynamic list of methods of my class, but I am just afraid that in the future my app will break if there's an update or something that will add new methods to the class (unknowingly).

**UPDATE:**

The 3 methods only get added in Rails 3 it seemed (the project I'm working on), but not in Rails 4 (as [@Wand Maker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/794242/wand-maker) and I have tested).

This is the exact code (where I removed already everything, but still getting same results/problem)

```
# lib/my_class.rb
class MyClass
  include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper

  def welcome
    puts 'Hello Jules!'
  end

  def farewell
    puts 'Goodbye Jules!'
  end
end

byebug
```

Or I could delete that file: my_class.rb (and copy and paste that whole code in `rails console`)

But, still getting the same problem.

Comment: FYI: If I use `MyClass < ActionController::Base` and use `MyClass.methods`, then, I see `default_url_options?` and other methods.  If I use `MyClass.methods(false)`, I don't see those methods.   Can you please share exact code how you are listing the methods and what is the base class of your real-life `MyClass`?

Comment: @WandMaker I updated the question with the exact stripped-down code where I am still getting the three methods.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do something like below:

```
MyClass.instance_methods(false)
#=> [:foo, :bar]
```

If you want to include any class methods defined in `MyClass`, you could do:

```
MyClass.instance_methods(false) + MyClass.singleton_methods(false)
```

---

Here is working example with all classes/modules defined

```
class BaseClass
  def moo
  end
end

module AnotherBaseClass
  def boo
  end
end

module MyModule
  def roo
  end
end

class MyClass < BaseClass
  extend AnotherBaseClass
  include MyModule

  def self.goo
  end

  def foo
  end

  def bar
  end
end

p MyClass.instance_methods(false) + MyClass.singleton_methods(false)
#=> [:foo, :bar, :goo]

p RUBY_VERSION
#=> "2.2.2"
```

Comment: That will still return methods defined in included Modules.

Comment: @zwippie I see. I have added full example, it seems to not do what you are saying.  Let me know if I overlooked something.

Comment: Try `Fixnum.instance_methods(false)` in `pry`.

Comment: @WandMaker Your (corrected) example does indeed return the correct methods, but I'm still trying to figure out if this is always working. For example, if I open a rails console and try `MyModel.instance_methods(false)` (where `MyModel` is an ActiveRecord class), I still get tons of methods not directly defined in `MyModel`, like all the `before_/after_` hooks.

Comment: @mudasobwa It returns an array of 36 method names - same 36 methods listed in documentation - http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Fixnum.html, does not have any methods from parent `Integer`

Comment: @WandMaker indeed, outside of Rails it likely returns correct results. Inside rails console it drives bonkers :)

Comment: @WandMaker you're code perfectly works when I run it. However, I am still in a problem specifically that I am including ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper in one of my class in Rails. When I include that, I always get extra methods:  default_url_options?, default_url_options=, default_url_options. Maybe this outside already of my question because it is specific in Rails. I just thought that `include` should behave the same way regardless of Rails or not. Any idea why I am getting these extra methods?

Comment: I even added byebug at the end of that file of my custom class, just so that I  could inspect immediately the class, and can be sure that Rails wont inject or add extra stuff to my class. But I am still getting extra default_url_options. I can remove these three manually from the array, but I am just afraid that (in my app im building), that there would be some  other new methods in the future that might pop-up, and then my app will break.

Comment: @Jay-ArPolidario AFAIK, RAILS is heavy on meta-programming, it defines methods dynamically to the given class if it includes certain module or extend a class.  I do not have answer to your specific query yet as when I include the said module `ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper` in the above code sample, I did not see additional methods getting added - may be there is more than that module.  Is your class a Controller?

Comment: @WandMaker I tried it on Rails 4, and now I do not have those methods. It seems that only in Rails 3.2 (the project I am working on) that those three methods get included. I actually copy and paste the whole class of mine into rails console, just so I am sure that Rails have already loaded everything, and that Rails won't add new methods to whatever code I run on the console. But still in Rails 3.2, those three methods still exists. Haha. Thank you for your answer though, I guess I will just manually remove these three methods for now :)

Comment: @zwippie, found nothing better than `.reject{|m| m =~ /\A(after|before|autosave|validate)/ }`

Comment: shortcut: .methods(false) returns an array of obj's public and protected singleton methods.